# How To Create A Quiz In Tkinter Using Buttons

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I am trying to get a quiz to ask another question and load up answers related to that question once a button has been pressed. It loads up the first question, with one button which has the correct answer and 3 buttons with the wrong answer (which it is suppose to do as it is multiple choice) but when a button is pressed the new question doesn't load. It says that ID is not defined when I press a button.

So how do I loop it so a new ID comes up so a new question loads. The multiple choice works it is just the loop back.

```
class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Question_Counter = 0
        self.Correct_Answers = 0
        self.getQuest
        self.AnswerQuestion

        self.ID = random.randint(1,100)
        QuestionSet.add(self.ID)
        self.QuestionAsked = self.getQuest(self.ID)
        QuestionSet.add(self.QuestionAsked)
        Answers = [self.GetAnswer(self.ID)]
        self.CorrectAnswer = self.GetAnswer(self.ID)
        for ID in range(3):
            new_id = random.randint(1,100)
            while new_id in Answers:
                new_id = random.randint(1,100)
            Answers.append(self.GetAnswer(new_id))
        self.OriginalAnswers = Answers[:]
        print(self.CorrectAnswer)
        print(self.GetAnswer(self.ID))

        l1 = tk.Label(self, text = self.QuestionAsked)
        l1.grid(row = 2, column = 2, pady = 100)

        l2 = tk.Label(self, text ="/50")
        l2.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

        myID = random.randint(0,3)
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text = Answers[myID], command = self.AnswerQuestion)
        b1.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        del Answers[myID]

        myID = random.randint(0,2)
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text = Answers[myID], command = self.AnswerQuestion)
        b2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 10)
        del Answers[myID]

        myID = random.randint(0,1)
        b3 = tk.Button(self, text = Answers[myID], command = self.AnswerQuestion)
        b3.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
        del Answers[myID]

        b4 = tk.Button(self, text = Answers[0], command = self.AnswerQuestion)
        b4.grid(row = 4, column = 3, pady = 10)
        del Answers[0]

    def getQuest(self,ID):
        if self.Question_Counter < 50:
            RandomInt = random.randint(1,100)
            new_db = sqlite3.connect("QuestionsDatabase.db")
            c= new_db.cursor()
            return (c.execute("SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE QuestionID = {}".format(ID)).fetchone()[0])
            self.Loading(self)

    def GetAnswer(self,ID):
        new_db = sqlite3.connect("QuestionsDatabase.db")
        c= new_db.cursor()
        return (c.execute("SELECT ANSWER FROM ANSWERS WHERE AnswerID = {}".format(ID)).fetchone()[0])  

    def AnswerQuestion(self):
        if self.CorrectAnswer == self.GetAnswer(self.ID):
            self.Correct_Answers += 1
        self.Question_Counter += 1
        self.getQuest(self,ID)
```

Comment: Do a `print(ID)` in `def GetAnswer(...` and verify if **this** `ID` exists in `ASNWERS`.

Comment: Yes i did the print statement and the ID does carry over. It takes the question ID then the AnswerID, that is the same as the QuestionID, and three random IDs just as it is suppose to do.

Comment: However, in the def AnswerQuestion it does not.

Comment: There is a typo `.getQuest(self,ID)` should be `.getQuest(self.ID)`. Note the dot `.` instead of `,`